# Extract whole JSON with JSONPath?

Tags: json, jsonpath

I have to use the JSONPath in my implementation. How to extract the whole JSON as it is?

My JSON is

```
[{"data":"xxx#12#1","id":"7_0_0"},
 {"data":"xxx#12#1","id":"8_0_1"},
 {"data":"xxx#12#1","id":"9_1_0"},
 {"data":"xxx#12#1","id":"10_1_1"},
 {"data":"xxx#12#1","id":"11_2_0"},
 {"data":"xxx#12#1","id":"12_2_1"}]
```

For example when I try with the path

```
$..*
```

I got the JSON

```
[
 {
"data": "xxx#12#1",
"id": "7_0_0"
 },
 {
"data": "xxx#12#1",
"id": "8_0_1"
 },
 {
"data": "xxx#12#1",
"id": "9_1_0"
 },
 {
"data": "xxx#12#1",
"id": "10_1_1"
 },
 {
"data": "xxx#12#1",
"id": "11_2_0"
 },
 {
"data": "xxx#12#1",
"id": "12_2_1"
 },
 "xxx#12#1",
 "7_0_0",
 "xxx#12#1",
 "8_0_1",
 "xxx#12#1",
 "9_1_0",
 "xxx#12#1",
 "10_1_1",
 "xxx#12#1",
 "11_2_0",
 "xxx#12#1",
 "12_2_1"
 ]
```

So there are extra fields at the end of the JSON.

https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/index.html

http://jsonpath.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I use the path

```
*
```

I got the whole JSON.